# Break time-reversal symmetry in photonic system without using bias magnetic field

Tags: photons, symmetry-breaking, time-reversal-symmetry

In photonic system, e.g, photonic crystals, people usually use ferromagnetic material or so called Tellegen medium which acts as effective field bias to break the time-reversal symmetry. I just want to know whether there are other ways to break T symmetry. I mean in a system without loss.

Comment: Any lossy process will do.

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear. I mean for lossless systems.

Comment: Any open lossless system will do as well.